# Reuse org.apache.cxf generated client instead of always regenerate

Tags: java, spring, soap, cxf

I am trying to store the automated generated client in a bean because I always see the following output in console which means it will always send a request to the SOAP server to generate the client which takes about 1 - 1 1/2 seconds or even longer.

```
Creating Service {http://example.com/soap/example}ExampleService from WSDL: https://test.example.com/soap/example?wsdl
```

The generated looks like following

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://example.com/soap/example", name = "Example")
@XmlSeeAlso({com.example.soap.packe.ObjectFactory.class, ObjectFactory.class})
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface Example { ... }



@WebServiceClient(name = "ExampleService",
                  wsdlLocation = "http://example.com/soap/example?wsdl",
                  targetNamespace = "http://example.com/soap/example")
public class ExampleService extends Service {

@WebEndpoint(name = "ExampleServiceProd")
public Example getExampleForProd() {
    return super.getPort(ExampleServiceProd, Example.class);
}

@WebEndpoint(name = "ExampleServiceTest")
public Example getExampleForTest() {
    return super.getPort(ExampleServiceTest, Example.class);
}
```

What I have tried:

```
private final ExampleService exampleService;    
@Bean
    @RequestScope
    public Example getExample() {
        final EnvConfig envConfig = someService.getEnvConfig();
        if (envConfig.isProd())
            return someService.getExampleForTest();
        return someService.getExampleForProd();
    }
```

It is annotated with `@RequestScope` as configuration may change during runtime. Calling `getExampleForXXX` seems to always regenerate the client (regarding the above posted log) which takes about 1 - 1 1/2 seconds.

Then I've tried the following approach

```
private final Map<EnvConfig, Example> examples = new HashMap<>();
private final ExampleService exampleService;
@Bean
@RequestScope
public Example getExample() {
    final EnvConfig envConfig = someService.getEnvConfig();
    if (!examples.containsKey(accessDataEntity)) {
        if (envConfig.isProd())
            examples.put(envConfig, exampleService.getExampleForProd());
        else
            examples.put(envConfig, exampleService.getExampleForTest());
    }    
    return wallets.get(envConfig);
}
```

This seems to work at first but on the second request, when getting `Example` from the `Map`, I always face the following exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The client has been closed.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:99)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy246.hashCode(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:964)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.requiresDestruction(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:393)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.filterPostProcessors(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.<init>(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.registerDisposableBeanIfNecessary(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1878)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:636)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    ... 127 common frames omitted

Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.getExample' defined in class path resource [com/example/ExampleConfig.class]: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The client has been closed.]
```

Is there a way to generate the client once and reuse it to avoid generating the client on each request